# prolog: built-in or other method to use function-like return values

Tags: prolog, logic, gnu

I'm trying to let Prolog instantiate a variable to the opposite key of a public/private key pair, if that is even possible.

So I basically have:

```
publicKey(k_c).
privateKey(k_c-1).

keyPair(k_c,k_c-1).
```

Given the nature of Prolog I don't think you could manage something like

```
inverseOf(X) :-
(keyPair(X,Y), return(Y),!);(keyPair(Y,X),return(Y),!).
```

Why I want/need this?

I have a rule

```
init(Init_1, Init_2,Init_3)
```

and I want to check for something like

```
Init_3 == inverseOf(Init_2).
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define

```
inverseOf(X, Y):- keyPair(X,Y), !.
inverseOf(X, Y):- keyPair(Y,X), !.
```

and then use

```
inverseOf(Init_2, Init_3).
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm ignoring the forest because of all those trees, it seems.

Answer (score 1):

With something like this defined:

```
keypair(pub1, priv1).
keypair(pub2, priv2).
keypair(pub3, priv3).

keymatch(A, B) :- keypair(A, B).
keymatch(A, B) :- keypair(B, A).
```

You could ask things like:

```
keymatch(pub1, X).
keymatch(priv2, X).
keymatch(priv3, pub3).
```

---

An aside...

Prolog does not have functions; you can't say something like `Y = f(X)` in Prolog (actually you can, but it doesn't do what you'd expect if you're coming from a C/Java/Python/etc background.

To implement the functionality of `Y = f(X)` in Prolog, you would do something like this

`f(X, Y) :- Y is X + 1.`

and invoke it like this

`f(3, Y).`

Y would evaluate to the value 4.